# Is Robinsonian Semantics a special case of Tarskian Semantics?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Like the question says,

Putting all the nitty-gritty aside, Tarksi semantics boils down to an assignment function that maps a sequence of elements in the universe to a set of variables in a term.

Robinson takes another approach:

consider a language $L$ and structure $\scr S$ of $L$ and universe $S$. Instead of including an assignment function, we take an expansion of $L$, $L^+$, which is just $\scr {S}$ $\cup$ $C$ where $C$ includes a constant $c_i$ for each $s_i$ in $S$.

I can't prove this, but I think every Robinsonian term is a Tarksian term with the only difference being: if we consider a Robinsonian term within $\scr S$ it just has a particular assignment-namely- $\bar c$ which is from $C$.

Comment: Can you add more details on Robinson semantics? How is the validity relation defined between models and (Robinson) formulas?

Comment: @Berci Hi, please have a look over Mr. Schweber's answer. But in General, Robinson's is slightly more complicated: we say $\scr S \models \phi$ iff $\scr S^{+} \models \phi$ (constant assignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a substantive difference between the two (and I've never heard the term "Robinson semantics" before - I've seen both approaches subsumed by the term "Tarskian semantics"). Basically, in order to recursively define the satisfaction relation for normal sentences, it turns out that we have to consider some kind of "generalized sentence" along the way due to the behavior of quantifiers. There are two reasonable ways to get such a generalization, namely **variable assignments** or **parameters in the syntax**. These do exactly the same thing, but look different on the surface.

---

Using the terminology in the OP, here's a possibly-overly-detailed description of the situation. Tarskian semantics recursively defines a class $\mathfrak{C}_{Tarski}$ of **triples** of the form $(\mathcal{A},\varphi,\nu)$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure in some language $L$, $\varphi$ is an $L$-formula, and $\nu$ is an assignment of elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ to the free variables in $\varphi$: we have $(\mathcal{A},\varphi,\nu)\in\mathfrak{C}_{Tarsk}$ iff $\mathcal{A},\nu\models\varphi$ in the Tarskian sense. Similarly, Robinsonian semantics recursively defines a class $\mathfrak{C}_{Robinson}$ of **pairs** of the form $(\mathcal{A},\hat{\varphi})$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure in some language $L$ and $\hat{\varphi}$ is a sentence in the language $L_\mathcal{A}$ gotten by adding to $L$ a constant symbol for each element of $\mathcal{A}$: we have $(\mathcal{A},\hat{\varphi})\in\mathfrak{C}_{Tarsk}$ iff $\mathcal{A}\models\hat{\varphi}$ in the Robinsonian sense.

The point is that $\mathfrak{C}_{Tarsk}$ and $\mathfrak{C}_{Robinson}$ are really equivalent. For example, fix a structure $\mathcal{A}$ in a language $L$ and an $L_\mathcal{A}$-sentence $\hat{\varphi}$. Let $c_{a_1},...,c_{a_n}$ be the "$\mathcal{A}$-constants" appearing in $\hat{\varphi}$, let $x_1,...,x_n$ be variables not occurring in $\hat{\varphi}$, and let $(\varphi,\nu)$ be the following pair:

- $\varphi$ is the $L$-formula gotten by replacing each "$c_{a_i}$" in $\hat{\varphi}$ by "$x_i$," and
- $\nu:\{x_1,...,x_n\}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}: x_i\mapsto a_i$ is the variable assignment "remembering" what we've replaced.

We have $(\mathcal{A},\hat{\varphi})\in\mathfrak{C}_{Robinson}$ iff $(\mathcal{A},\varphi,\nu)\in \mathfrak{C}_{Tarski}$. And we can similarly translate the other way. So *(up to annoying variable/constant symbol naming issues)* Tarski and Robinson provide exactly the same picture. In particular, we have:

> Suppose $\varphi$ is an $L$-sentence and $\mathcal{A}$ is an $L$-structure. Then $$(\mathcal{A},\varphi,\emptyset)\in\mathfrak{C}_{Tarski}\quad\iff\quad(\mathcal{A},\varphi)\in\mathfrak{C}_{Robinson}.$$ (Note that $\emptyset$ is indeed a variable assignment for $\varphi$ since $\varphi$, being a sentence, has no free variables whatsoever.)

Comment: Thank you for the Indepth answer. If you don't mind can you please answer the last part: can we have equality between Tarski/Robinson terms?

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost What is a Tarski/Robinson term in the first place? (I don't understand how "term" is being used here.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using "term" for formula. A Robinson term will be $t(\bar a)$ [$\bar a$ being an assignment]= Tarski term $t(\bar v)$ [v being a sequence of variables]. I am asking if this equality is true.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Ah. Then the situation is the following. First of all, a Robinson term has an additional parameter: the structure $\mathcal{A}$ from which the tuple $\overline{a}$ is taken. So it should be denoted something like "$(t(\overline{a}),\mathcal{A})$." By contrast a Tarski term makes sense without specifying a structure or variable assignment. The idea is that a Robinson term is a "specified" Tarski term - the equivalence is between Robinson terms and Tarski terms *augmented with* variable assignments to elements of a specific structure.

Comment: Think of a Tarski term as an **incomplete descriptor**, and a Robinson term - or equivalently, a Tarski term equipped with a specific choice of structure-and-variable-assignment - as a complete descriptor. (Note that we could also observe that each Tarski term corresponds to a *class of* Robinson terms, namely all of its *instantiations*: to $t(\overline{v})$ we assign the class of all $(t(\overline{a}),\mathcal{A})$s. Picking a structure-and-variable-assignment amounts to picking a Robinson term from this class.)

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!